# Command works in shell but not Objective-C or C

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, sshfs

I want to run the following shell command in Objective-C

`sshfs -C -p 22 user@remote.computer.com ~/local/directory/path`

using the command `system("sshfs -C -p 22 user@remote.computer.com ~/local/directory/path");`

but I get `sh: sshfs: command not found` in NSLog.

If I copy and paste it into terminal however, it works.

Comment: Where are you running the program from is it an app or the command line and where is sshfs

Comment: The program is running from a Cocoa app, and sshfs is located in /Users/username/Projects

Answer (score 2):

The path used by an GUI application does not include any changes you have made in your shell files in your home directory (e.g. ~/.bashrc)

One way is to use the full path in the system call. (i.e. /Users/username/Projects - ~ are not automatically expanded) In a Cocoa app I would use NSTask to give more control